# Optimal way to transfer data from marketing cloud to external server?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-export

I'm trying to extract data from Salesforce MC to my server so that i could apply my custom machine learning algorithm..What is the optimal way to do it.currently i'm using Rest and SOAP API

Comment: Adarsh, please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications. That is not what comments are for. Requesting clarification via comments is fine, but providing it should go into your original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting data out of Salesforce Marketing Cloud (and into another platform) can be done a few different ways; including:

- FTP [Extracts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_use_a_data_extract_activity.htm&type=5)/[Transfers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_file_transfer_activity.htm&type=5)
- APIs ([REST/SOAP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm))
- Connectors

Based on the information you've given in the comments - you are looking to extract Subscriber & Tracking/Conversion data for Reporting purposes.
I use the following solution to [extract data](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_use_a_data_extract_activity.htm&type=5) for analysis on a daily automation:

1. Create a [Tracking Extract](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_tracking_extract.htm&type=5) activity for the data you need (Conversions, etc).
2. Create a [File Transfer](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_file_transfer_activity.htm&type=5) activity to move the tracking data from the Safe House into your FTP. 
   **Note**: Depending on your tracking activity setup, you may need to include a "Manage File" File Transfer activity to Unzip your tracking data.
3. Send the data to your server using a File Transfer activity and a [File Location](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_file_locations.htm&type=5). The guide in RiskForce's answer is a good place to start.

With regards to Subscriber Extracts - exporting your entire database every day is very inefficient. If your data is stored in a Data Extension (and each subscriber/record has a "Last Modified Date" or similar value) then you can create [Deltas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) to lighten the amount of data being transfered.

1. Create a Data Extension for temporary storing the Delta - Call it [Subscriber Delta]
2. Create a SQL Query Activity to query your "My Subscribers" for records that have changed in the last 24 hours, and then save/overwrite that data into the new [Subscriber Delta]. Example:

   SELECT
    SubscriberKey
    ,EmailAddress
    ,LastModifiedDate
   FROM [My Subscribers]
   WHERE LastModifiedDate >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
3. Now that you have all records that have been changed/updated in the last 24 hours, create a Data Extract activity and File Transfer activity in Automation Studio to extract the data from [Subscriber Delta], and move it from the Safe House into your external FTP location.

The final automation will look something like this:
[image]

Some of these activities can be tricky to setup - so take small steps, read the Salesforce documentation, and let us know if you need any further assistance. Good luck!

Comment: Why can't I just use REST/SOAP api for bulk data transfer?

Comment: I don’t believe you can access Conversions (or other tracking data) using the API services. Both REST & SOAP APIs have limitations on how much data you can transfer per call. APIs are better for getting small amounts of data very often, while the method I show above is better for large amounts of data less often.

Comment: In the offical documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm  it is mentioned like SOAP api could be used for tracking data..Can u please clarify what type of data you meant by  "Conversions(or other tracking data)" ?

Comment: Hey Adam - In your original comments (that have been deleted) you mentioned "Conversions" as one of the insights you wanted to extract. I haven't found documentation to extract Conversions specifically using APIs; I've only seen it done via the Tracking Extract. However since you only want the data for analytical purposes - and don't need it in real time - doing a daily CSV extract (using the above method) will be much simpler than developing an API connection. Conversions = https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_tracking_extract.htm&type=5. Apologies if this is not what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps for your needs the most efficient way to go would be to create full dumps of your data extensions using the data extract activity in automation studio: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_use_a_data_extract_activity.htm&type=5

You can then transfer the file to an external SFTP-site using the file transfer activity: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_create_a_file_transfer_activity.htm&type=5

Check this document on how to create a file transfer location so you can configure your own SFTP as a location to transfer to:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_create_file_transfer_location.htm&type=5

I hope this helps a bit!